# How to remove CAGradientLayer from UIButton when it's highlighted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, cagradientlayer

I've added gradient effect for my Button and added it as a sub layer to my `Button`.

**Code is :**

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.frame = self.myButton.layer.bounds;
gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5].CGColor,(id) colorTwo.CGColor,(id) colorThree.CGColor,(id) colorFour.CGColor, nil];
gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f], nil];
self.myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
gradientLayer.cornerRadius = self.myButton.layer.cornerRadius;
[self.myButton.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

Now when my button is highlighted (touchedDown method called), I want to set new gradient to myButton. Hence I need to remove the old gradient effect when myButton is clicked and add new gradient.

How to remove the old gradient effect ?

I tried

```
for (CALayer *layer in [self.loginScreenView.btnPowerBroking.layer.sublayers copy]){
        if ([[layer name] isEqualToString:@"gradientLayer"]) {
            NSLog(@"Gradient layer found.");
        }
    }
```

But I can't get it's gradient layer.

Thanks for your time. (:

Comment: Thanks for the Edit. I forgot to notice these small things in the Question. I'll have these in mind while asking next question. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't set the `name` property to your `gradientLayer` object just set it and it will work.

```
 gradientLayer.name = @"gradientLayer";
 [self.myButton.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

In for loop's `if statement` remove the layer using this `[layer removeFromSuperlayer];`

**Note :** You are adding layer in `myButton` object in searching inside the `btnPowerBroking` check properly for that also, you need to search in button where you have added `Layer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method...

```
[self.myButton.layer replaceSublayer:oldgradientLayer with:newgradientLayer];
```